# Log Stream Not creating when i run lambda using serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

i created a log group for my lambda using cloud formation, and i when i run my cloudformation scripts, the lambda function includes the cloudwatch log trigger. When i invoke the lambda, the log group i created using the cloudformation doesn’t have any log stream in it, but it seems cloudformation automatically creates a log group for the lambda regardless if i am creating one using cloudformation and including it to the function.

Is there any advice please?

'''

```
resources:
  Resources:
    AccessLogs:
      Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
      Properties:
        LogGroupName: /aws/lambda/${self:service}-dev-AccessLogs
        RetentionInDays: 7
    LambdaExecutionRole:
      Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action:
                - 'sts:AssumeRole'
        Policies:
        - PolicyName: logpolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'

'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign an arbitrary log group to a Lambda function. There's an open [Feature Request](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/147) for it.

If you simply want to change the log retention policy then you might be able to do that using [this technique](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=811315), but it still does not allow you to control the log group name.